# Exclude the endpoints of an interval

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, intervals

I have a 2D mesh with an interval of Xleft = -1.5 Xright = 1.5, Ydown = -1.5 Yup = 1.5.
Nx and Ny are the variables that indicate how many intervals I want. The problem originates in 1D, so let's go to 1D to simplify.

My interval is [-1.5,1.5] and let's take N=12. My grid-step will be 3/12 = 0.25. I want to output an array with the inner points: (-1.5, 1.5). I use the following function.

for 2D

```
np.mgrid[intervalX,intervalY]
```

for 1D

```
np.mgrid[intervalX] = np.mgrid[start:stop:stepsize]
```

Because the start will be the literal start and the stop will be the stop - dx. I define the array of inner points as:

```
LeftX  = -1.5
RightX =  1.5

Nx = 12 

x_int = RightX - LeftX #interval in the x-direction

dx = (RightX - LeftX)  / Nx #grid step in x-direction

matrix0 = np.mgrid[LeftX+dx:RightX:(x_int/Nx)]
```

the output as expected is:

```
[-1.25 -1.   -0.75 -0.5  -0.25  0.    0.25  0.5   0.75  1.    1.25]
```

Most of the time it goes right.

But in some cases with a specific N, the program does something unexpected:

The output for N=9:

```
[-1.16666667 -0.83333333 -0.5        -0.16666667  0.16666667  0.5
  0.83333333  1.16666667  1.5]
```

You see that the right boundary point is included in the array. I would expect the same array expect for the most right 1.5. But this is unwanted. The same happens with N=10 or N=22.

- **Question: Why does this happen?**
- **Question: How can I change my code so this doesn't happen anymore?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is basically a numerical rounding error.
[Some more information](https://floating-point-gui.de).

What happens inside `mgrid[start:end:step]` (or `arange`) can be simplified  as something like this:

```py
def mgrid(start, end, step)
    a = [start]
    i = 1
    while start+i*step < end:
        a.append(start+i*step)
        i += 1
    return a
```

To use your numbers as an example and show where it fails:

```
LeftX = -1.5
RightX = 1.5
Nx = 9
dx = (RightX - LeftX) / Nx

#    start        + i * step
a8 = (LeftX + dx) + 8 * dx 
# 1.4999999999999998
a8 < RightX
# True
```

so `a8` is numerically slightly smaller than your endpoint `1.5` and is therefore added to the interval. Nevertheless it is displayed as `1.5` because it is pretty close.

As a solution you could use the `np.linspace()` function.
The result includes by default the start and endpoint and you could use just the elements `x[1:-1]`, or shift the start and end point:

```
import numpy as np
x1 = np.linspace(LeftX, RigthX, Nx+1)x[1, :-1]
x2 = np.linspace(LeftX+dx, RightX-dx, Nx-1)
```

By including the endpoints explicitly you don't have to worry if the
check `start + i*step < end` gives a wrong result for your last `index`  due to a rounding error.

Alternatively you could use a small epsilon for which you know it is definitely smaller than your step size and do something like this:

```
eps = 1e-10
np.mgrid[LeftX+dx:RightX-eps:dx]
```

By subtracting this epsilon you make sure the check `start + i*step < end` always gives the expected result.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I tried that already. it is mandatory (for uni assignment) to use np.mgrid[] function. In the end I need to have a 2D mesh as output. Unfortunately I cannot include a np.linspace in the np.mgrid function.

Comment: `mgrid` uses `arange` or `linspace`.  It's the `arange` use that's giving the inconsistent results.  If the `step` is an imaginary value, it will use `linspace` to generate the values. https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.mgrid.html

Answer (score 1):

For a non integer step Please use *numpy linspace* since it has better handling of endpoints

```py
np.linspace(LeftX, RightX, Nx, endpoint=False)
```

then for 2D you can use *numpy meshgrid*

```py
x= np.linspace(LeftX, RightX, Nx, endpoint=False)
y = np.linspace(LeftY, RightY, Ny, endpoint=False)
xv, yv = np.meshgrid(x, y)
```